# Public and Private key Encryption in ANT

Tags: rest-api, ant, csv, ftp

We need a solution for storing salesforce object's data as flat files in a S FTP folder as .csv files. But salesforce is not supporting to send files to S FTP/FTP. So we are trying to build a solution in ANT by querying data from salesforce and making them as CSV and pushing it to S FTP.

But does ant support's PEG(public and private key) encryption for encrypting the files before sending it to S FTP.

OR

Are there any better solution for sending files to SFTP from salesforce over PEG encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is encrypt the file using PGP from the ant process.

This is independent from salesforce. What you can do is execute the PGP shell command using something like:

```
<exec executable="sh" >
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="echo ${encrypted.passphrase} | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output ${data.dir}/salesforce.csv --decrypt ${data.dir.encrypted}/${encrypted.file.name}"/>
</exec>
```